# Change naming pattern in Angular-CLI

Tags: angular-cli

Angular-CLI automatically generates files using dashes and dots from a component name written in UpperCamelCase like this:

`components/MyCoolComponent -> components/my-cool/my-cool.component.ts`

I suppose this follows the official styleguide but what if i want to change the way names are generated? Is there a smart way to configure this?

Comment: At the moment this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not the supported. You can see the discussion here - 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/208